# TFS .NET client libraries finding merge related work items

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-2015, tfs-workitem, workitem

I want to build a Query App that, which will query a branch in TFS, and retrieve all work items and display it as Master Detail report as such:

```
User Story:30669    [Closed]    Ongoing Support and Maintenance
    Task:31566      [Closed]    Upgrade latest version of client libraries
    Bug:30905       [Closed]    Executing Error "The given Key was not present in the dictionary"
User Story:30351    [Closed]    Add new Function
    Task:28188      [Closed]    Implement new Function
```

This will give us a good idea, of what work we have done on a given branch, and what will be in a build if we choose to build.

So currently I can retrieve all the work items for a branch between dates, excluding merges.  I want to include merges, but I am struggling to understand TFS client interface.

This is what I have so far: The `BranchModel`, `ChangesetModel`, `UserStories`, and `TaskBugs` are classes to help me arrange `WorkItem` objects for the output report:

```
        const String c_collectionUri = "http://tfsServer:81/tfs/ProjectCollection";
        const String c_projectName = "Project";

        using (TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = 
               new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(c_collectionUri)))
        {
            VersionControlServer vcServer =
                 tpc.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
            WorkItemStore workItemStore = tpc.GetService<WorkItemStore>();

            // Fetch the branch history
            var history = vcServer.QueryHistory(@"$/ProjectCollection/Project/Branch1/Source", RecursionType.Full)
                .Where(h => h.CreationDate >= new DateTime(2018, 1, 1) && h.CreationDate <= new DateTime(2018, 1, 5));

            BranchModel branch = new BranchModel("Branch1");

            // Get the changesets, for from the fetched history
            List<Changeset> changesets = new List<Changeset>();
            foreach (Changeset changeset in history)
            {
                changesets.Add(changeset);

                // TODO: Add code to get Changesets related to merge
            }

            // Get the WorkItems from Changesets Fetched 
            foreach (Changeset changeset in changesets)
            {
                ChangesetModel changesetModel = branch.AddChangeset(changeset);

                foreach (WorkItem workItem in changeset.WorkItems)
                {
                    //  Fetch the UserStory for a Bug/Task
                    foreach (var linkedItem in workItem.Links)
                    {
                        RelatedLink relatedItem = linkedItem as RelatedLink;
                        WorkItem userStory = null;

                        if (relatedItem != null)
                            userStory = GetWorkItem(workItemStore, c_projectName, relatedItem.RelatedWorkItemId);

                        if (userStory != null)
                        {
                            var userStoryModel = branch.AddUserStory(userStory);
                            var taskBugModel = userStoryModel.Add(workItem);
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

            // Finally print the report
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Related Work:");
            Console.WriteLine("=".PadLeft(80, '='));

            foreach (var userStory in branch.UserStories)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(userStory.Value.ToString());

                foreach (var taskBug in userStory.Value.TaskBugs)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(taskBug.Value.ToString());
                }
            }
```

And the Method for GetWorkItem:

```
    void WorkItem GetWorkItem(WorkItemStore workItemStore, string c_projectName, int workitemID)
    {
        return workItemStore.Projects[c_projectName].Store.GetWorkItem(workitemID);
    }
```

I would like to know, for a `Changeset` that happens to be a merge, how to get it's related work items related to that merge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get the related work items directly from the merge changeset. You need to get the merge history (`version from` , `version to`), then retrieve the related work items from the `version from` and `version to` changesets.

You can use the [`VersionControlServer.GetChangesForChangeset`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff736102(v=vs.120).aspx) Method to get the merge history for the merge changeset.  Then Get the WorkItems from the history Changesets Fetched.

Below sample for your reference to get the merge changeset history:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection"));
            new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
            tpc.EnsureAuthenticated();
            VersionControlServer vcs = tpc.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

            int cid = 376;

            //List<IChangesetSummary> changeSets = InformationNodeConverters.GetAssociatedChangesets(build);
            IEnumerable<Change> changes = vcs.GetChangesForChangeset(cid, false, Int32.MaxValue, null, null, true);

            foreach (Change change in changes)
            {
                if ((change.ChangeType & ChangeType.Merge) == 0) continue;
                foreach (var m in change.MergeSources)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3}", change.Item.ChangesetId, m.ServerItem, m.VersionFrom, m.VersionTo);
                }                   
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: Thank you @Andy, your answer was the answer to my question here. But only a piece to the final solution I am developing.  For those reading this just an FYI.